# Multi-Value Request Headers in PHP

Tags: php, http, curl, symfony

Let's say I have a plain new Symfony 2.8 or 3.2 installation. In my main controller action I do this:

```
dump($request->headers->all());
```

After starting built-in web server and sending this request using curl,

```
curl 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip' -H 'accept-encoding: deflate' -H 'accept-encoding: identity'
```

I get this "accept-encoding" header value dumped:

```
[accept-encoding] => Array
(
    [0] => gzip
)
```

I expect another two values to be in the array too. This happens not only with "accept-encoding" header, but with other headers too, having more than one value defined this way.

Does PHP not handle that? I am using PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass header values separated by comma:
`curl 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, identity'`

Comment: Yes, this way, it works. It is strange, however, that the other way is not working, because according to the HTTP RFC, it is also valid. I guess, I will have to stick to using the comma-separated list.

Comment: I believe "issue" is in `curl` client not in the way PHP treats HTTP request.